# matplotlib's scatter plot changes the axis of another plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, scatter-plot

I want to combine a `contourf()` plot and a `scatter()` plot from `matplotlib.pyplot`, however, adding the scatter plot changes the axis of the plot. Here a small example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(10,10)
plt.contourf(data)
# plt.scatter(3, 7, s=200, color='k')
plt.show()
```

This script creates some plot like the this:

[image: without scatter()]

When uncommenting `plt.scatter(3, 7, s=200, color='k')` the axis limits are changed, resulting in a white frame around the contour plot.
A possibility is to manually set the axis limits using `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim`, but it seems an unnecessary hassle. How can I elegantly make this work?

[image: with scatter()]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add

```
plt.xlim(auto=False)
plt.ylim(auto=False)
```

right after `countorf` line; or you may always do

```
xl, yl = plt.xlim(), plt.ylim()
```

anywhere in your code that you are happy with `x,y` limits, and then at the end do

```
plt.xlim(xl)
plt.ylim(yl)
```

Comment: Very useful. I am now using your first example.